# The perspective in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I have issue with perspective in Unity. I'm just making a game alone and I have no idea how to fix the problem. I'm going to show you the problem on screenshots.

*On the images, **yellow** color == **collider** lines*

I want to go to the building closer.
I can't make collider like this:

[image]

Because it looks weird. I want it like this:

[image]

But to do this I have to change collider to something like this:

[image]

But there is still other issue... I can't go behind the building because the player won't "hide" behind the building like this:

[image]

Player will stop walking here:

[image]

---

I have no idea what to do now. I was trying to figure it out in any way. I was searching ideas/informations everywhere. I've run out of ideas, so I'm asking you here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your collider doesn't have to be the full size of your sprite. For the first issue, just set the collider on the lower half of the body. For the second issue, excluse the top of the building from its collider. Though you probably have to make two distinct sprites for the building, so that you can put a higher z-index for the top of the building (otherwise the player will be drawn on top of it)

Comment: Have you tried to put your Collider in the middle of your Character, thus leaving enough space on either side? You could also try to make two seperate Colliders that are merely a line (i.e. with a very small height), thus being able to fine tune the boundaries. You aren't limited to one collider per object ;)

Comment: @KevinGosse , Yes, i was thinking about that z-index, but it's so complicated and i'm planning to add more buildings in the future and this means that I will have to make 2 sprites for each buiding and set collider manually for each building. Now i use tilemap collider.

Comment: @loptrinho hmm, collider in the middle is a nice idea, but there is still problem with order in layers/z-index. I was trying to do two colliders.

Comment: @Krystian, I suggest you an approach with several Layers of Sprite. In the lowest layer, you draw floor. In the second, you draw buildings and objects that are collidable. In the third, you draw roofs, tree-tops, smoke... Things you want to appear over the hero. (Three is a suggestion, you can have more or less). If you like the idea, tell me and I write a proper answer.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I found the other way. I placed collider in the middle, set it to very small height and then i will change the order in layer if position of player > position of object.

Comment: Are you using the tilemap feature of Unity?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Yes, but i change the decorations like tables/chairs to prefabs